# Android Studio won't compile

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to compile (debug) the "HelloWorld" Chromecast Android app supplied by Google on their GitHub page.

After doing numerous updates to the SDK and Android Studio, I am now totally stuck on getting this to run.

I have not changed any code that was supplied.

The current error I get when clicking "debug" is:

"NoSuchMethodError: com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavor.getMinSdkVersion()I: com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavor.getMinSdkVersion()I"

I cannot find any information on this error.

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
}
```

Comment: paste your `build.gradle` of your application

Answer (score 2):

You can try to go in the manifest file and can change the minimum sdk version

Comment: I set the minimum and target SDK to 19, it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Split your gradle.build:

On the gradle.build of your project leave:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
   }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And on the gradle.build of your module declare:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
}
```

[image: Gradle configuration files]
Put the first code on project gradle configuration and the secod part of code on module gradle configuration file.

Comment: To clarify, I have no idea how to use Gradle. I come from an Eclipse background, so Android Studio is new to me. How do I "split" the build.gradle file (e.g. where do I put the different parts, what should they be named etc?)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you just need to update your Gradle tools version. This line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

should be:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
```

Android Studio 0.8+ requires at least 0.12 to properly build your project.

Comment: You can't do an in-place update from 0.5.1 to 0.8 -- you'll have to install the downloaded 0.8 update manually.

Comment: My original version was 0.2 something, guess thats why it didn't update to 0.8 properly :)

Comment: Haha, that'll do it. I believe in 0.11 or 0.12 they updated the minSdkVersion field to be an enum vs just an integer value (probably to prepare for the new 'android-L' value for the preview SDK)